# Flutter Audio Player

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, audio, stream

I have a playlist in flutter.
i am playing list of sounds i have added

```
audioPlayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
```

this listener there which continues the play list once url is end.
The problem is that once started now you dont have any option to cancel or stop or close this lisner and stop the audio

i have tried

```
StreamSubscription<void>? completionSubscription;
```

and assign

```
 completionSubscription= audioPlayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
          if (isNextAutoPlayEnabled && currentIndex < Constants.cities.length) {
            currentIndex++;
            final nextUrl = generateURL(Constants.selectedCountry!.Sura_No, currentIndex+1);
            print("Next URL: $nextUrl");
            audioPlayer.play(nextUrl, isLocal: false);
```

this but this says that "Null check operator used on a null value"
and anyhow it is not cancelling